# How to prevent page from caching in Firefox using Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, firefox, caching, greasemonkey

I need to write a Greasemonkey script which will prevent Firefox from caching certain pages.  Is that possible at all?

I know it's possible to reload a page with

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

-- but the script won't even run when page is loaded from cache, and even if it runs, how do I know that page is loaded from cache and not from URL?

I know that adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="No-Cache">
```

to HTML of the page would do the trick, but  is only parsed at the initial load, and adding it thru GM does not work...

So, how do I achieve this?  Is it possible with GM at all?

Comment: Re: `the script won't even run when page is loaded from cache`. Then cache is not your issue. Most likely the page is AJAX driven.  Scripts run regardless of whether the page was loaded from cache.

Comment: Well, If I had the script which could affect 'meta' tags before they are interpreted by the browser, then I would always be able force refresh the page I need, making it run the script, and set up all the metatags needed to prevent browser from caching, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the page from being cached, but you may be able to do the next best thing and add a cache-buster.

http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/

```
function() {
  // var url = window.location.href;
  var url = "http://z.invalid?cachebuster=10";

  var bits = url.split('?');
  var newUrl = bits[0];

  newUrl += "?cachebuster=" + Math.random()*10000000000000000;
  window.location.href = newUrl;
}
```